# How to create a download link in XSL

Tags: xslt

I'm new at XSLT. I want to create a hyperlink using XSLT. Should look like this:

**Document**

Document is the link and upon clicking this, download of a file should begin.

Any ideas? :)

Thanks

Comment: it's not quite clear what you want to do. can you provide some code you tried

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a hyperlink in XSLT or XML. If you're generating HTML with your XSLT, then you just need to output the appropriate elements and attributes, which you can do literally if you want, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="somethingthatgeneratesalink">
  <a href="http://example.com/">This is a link to example.com</a>
</xsl:template>
```